# Startup script to generate uninstall command

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, startupscript

I have a text file of the format:

```
computername1 uninstallkey1
computername2 uninstallkey2
...
computername200 uninstallkey200
```

I am trying to write a startup script (batch file or powershell?) that generates a msiexec command that looks up and implants the correct key for each computer it executes on e.g.:

```
msiexec /x install.msi key=uninstallkey
```

If I have not made anything clear, please ask and any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "tokens=1*" %%i IN (yourtextfilename.txt) DO (
 IF /i %%i==%COMPUTERNAME% ECHO MSIEXEC /x install.msi key=%%j
)
```

This should do as you require - `yourtextfilename.txt` contains the data, presumably on a shared drive; finds the line where the computername in column 1 is the same as the computername returned by %computername% in the target computer's environment.

(all case-insensitive `EXCEPT` `%%i` and `%%j` which must match and be the same case)

Command simply `ECHO`ed - remove the `ECHO` keyword after verification to activate.

Comment: Thank you Peter for such a speedy and tidy answer, you've saved me hours!
Thanks again,

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell,

```
$comp = Import-CSV -Delimiter " " -Path C:\comp.txt -Header computername,uninstallkey
$comp | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($env:COMPUTERNAME -eq $_.Computername) { 
        Start-Process -FilePath "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/x install.msi key=$_.uninstallkey" 
    } 
}
```